# How do I import the logging library in Dart?

Tags: logging, import, dart

If I run:

> ```
> #!/home/jim/dart/dart-sdk/bin/dart
>
> #import('logging');
>
> Logger log = new Logger('');
>
> void main() {
>     log.warn("Hello, world!\n");
> }
> ```

I get:

> Unable to open file: /home/jim/Code/dart/test/logging'file:///home/jim/Code/dart/test/test-log.dart':
> Error: line 3 pos 1: library handler failed

Do I need to install the logger library? Where can I find it? How do I import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pub, the package manager for Dart.

In your pubspec.yaml, make sure you have a line for logging in the dependencies section:

```
name: mylib
description: My Library
dependencies:
  logging: any
```

Then run `pub install`, either in the Editor (Tools->Pub Install), or from the command line (`./dart/dart-sdk/bin/pub install`)

Then you can import logging with the `package:` scheme:

```
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
```

Comment: Thanks. Got logging "hello, world" going.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @caffinatedmonkey I'm not sure why it was rejected.